# What's the meaning of the expression "gold-plated commandos"?

Tags: meaning

One guy is leading a bunch of weird guys. They are hunting monsters. The leader says:

> I'd be surprised if either one of them could dream up gold-plated
>   Commandos.

The leader is talking about James Whale and Tod Browning.

I know that gold-plated means covered with a thin layer of gold, but I do not know exactly he means by saying *gold-plated Commandos*.

If the definition of [commando](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/commando) is

> a member of a military assault unit or team trained to
>   operate quickly and aggressively in especially urgent, threatening
>   situations,  as against terrorists holding hostages.

then I think *gold-plated commandos* do not have a pejorative meaning. Am I right?

Comment: It is not an expression. It is writing from an author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we kinda need better context to be more sane (as in, I'd like to see the panel/text where the quote comes from), but gold-plating and gold-plated I've seen used mainly as pejorative terms when applied to anything that's not supposed to be gold plated. Like a commando. Gold plating such an object would be an addition/augmentation that has pretty much nothing to do with what that object is for, but that would increase cost noticeably and therefore be kind of absurd (or wasteful, depending on your perspective).

Here's where context kicks in, and can lead me in a few directions:

If there are actual gold plated commandos (or say, commandos with an excess of guns to the point of absurdity, being led by a five-headed goldfish) being hunted and it's a bit unexpected?

> I'd be surprised if either one of them [Whale/Browning] could dream up something quite as strange as this.

Alternatively, if they're on a march and just talking, comparing their real-life jobs to a monster movie

> The founding fathers of monster movies dream up some pretty weird stuff, but I bet they couldn't come up with anything quite as strange as what we're hunting now.

This is a bit more of a stretch, but without seeing what's wrapped around the line, it's a bit hard to do much than guess.

Neither of those however, is positive, so as a roundabout way of getting back to it - I'd bet that yes, the term 'gold plated commandos' would be intended as a pejorative in *some* fashion. As to exactly *what* fashion, that's a bit harder...

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have this comic in my hands right now.

Comment: dangit.. what was the comic? I might see if i can get a copy to have a look at myself, am now curious..

Comment: Sorry! I do not remember what comic it was. I tried to translate that term to Portuguese about three years ago. I asked here: http://por.proz.com/kudoz/english_to_portuguese/cinema_film_tv_drama/3049094-dream_up_gold_plated_commandos.html

Answer (score 1):

> One guy is leading a bunch of weird guys. They are hunting monsters.

In what context does this take place?

Both [James Whale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Whale) and [Tod Browning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tod_Browning) were directors and the founding fathers of monster movies, so they are talking about the probability that either of these gentlemen could conceive of whatever monsters the guys to which you refer are hunting, which apparently can be described as *gold-plated commandos*.

*Gold-plated commandos* is being used pejoratively to describe the monsters being hunted.

Comment: Fine. But where's the *answer*?

Answer (score 0):

It's a pejorative phrase.  [This](http://www.commandocomics.com/) comic book site's "Gold Collection" publications are said to be "Gold Plated". They feature similar content and a universally poor narrative style. The speaker is implying that the subjects of the jab aren't even creative enough to come up with something cheesy like that.

Comment: @cornbreadninja, can you tell me what you edited?

Comment: :In this case, I do not understand the adjective "gold-plated" in this context. What I am missing here?

Comment: @spohreis I edited the answer to make the meaning clearer.

Comment: I corrected your spelling of 'pejorative'.  You can always click the 'edited' link to see what changes have been made and roll them back as you see fit.